# Does the actor claim in a GitHub Actions OIDC token show initial actor or triggering actor for a workflow re-run?

Tags: github-actions

I'm using [GitHub Actions with OIDC to connect to AWS](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services).  I want to restrict the role I am assuming so it can only be assumed when certain people trigger the workflow.

I see that the OIDC token has an `actor` claim (per [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect) and [this](https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com/.well-known/openid-configuration)).  I was reading about [differentiating triggering actor from executing actor](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-07-19-differentiating-triggering-actor-from-executing-actor/) in workflows, so at least in the [github context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) these are differentiated.  But what about in the token claim?  There is no triggering_actor claim (at present).

If a workflow is *re-run*, does the `actor` claim in the OIDC token show the *initial executing actor* or the *triggering actor*?

Comment: Unfortunately, from [this issue](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/issues/306) and [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#condition-keys-wif) I found that I won't be able to use the `actor` claim in my AWS policy anyway because it is not one of the supported keys.  So while my question remains, it is moot to me now.